# c# Dictionary<object, T> lookup value

Tags: c#, dictionary

Not sure how to best phrase this which is probably why I'm having difficulty looking it up. Here is a sample console application to demonstrate my meaning.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var item1 = new Item("Number");
        var item2 = new Item("Number");

        var dict = new Dictionary<Item, string>();
        dict.Add(item1, "Value");
        Console.WriteLine(dict.ContainsKey(item2));

        var dict2 = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        dict2.Add("Number", "Value");
        Console.WriteLine(dict2.ContainsKey("Number"));
        Console.Read();
    }

    class Item
    {
        readonly string number;
        public Item(string number)
        {
            this.number = number;
        }
    }
}
```

In this example `dict.ContainsKey(item2)` returns `false` and `dict2.ContainsKey("Number")` returns `true`. Can Item be defined in such a way that it would behave like a string?  The best I can come up with is

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
    var item1 = new Item("Number");
    var item2 = new Item("Number");

    var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    dict.Add(item1.ToString(), "Test");
    Console.WriteLine(dict.ContainsKey(item2.ToString()));
    Console.Read();
}

class Item
{
    readonly string number;

    public Item(string number)
    {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return number;
    }
}
```

This example is contrived, Item would have more fields and ToString() would joint them all up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to override `Equals` and `GetHashCode`. `Dictionary` use `Equals` and `GetHashCode` method to compare keys for equality.

```
class Item
{
    readonly string number;
    public Item(string number)
    {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return Equals(obj as Item);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        // this is c# 6 feature 
        return number?.GetHashCode() ?? 0;

        // If you are not using c# 6, you can use
        // return number == null ? 0 : number.GetHashCode();
    }

    private bool Equals(Item another)
    {
        if (another == null)
            return false;

        return number == another.number;
    }
}
```

If you have more than one field, you need to account all fields in the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` method.

Comment: I measured the performance difference and this approach is usually 10 times slower than using a `Dictionary<string, string>` and overriding `ToString()`. But you get the advantage of static type checking.

Comment: Beware of premature optimization http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil

Comment: The bigger thing you gain by not going the ToString() route is that the code is much more maintainable.  Someone in the future extending or modifying your class would expect that .Equals and .GetHashCode are used to test for logical equality.  They would NOT expect .ToString() to be used for that purpose.  And it's very unlikely that this performance difference actually matters.